# 12 bytes array to double python

Tags: python, double, type-conversion, arrays, precision

Im trying to do this:

```
struct.unpack('d', barray[:HALF_BYTES])[0]
```

Where `barray[:HALF_BYTES]` is a 12 bytes array

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "random_input_sample_drawer.py", line 19, in <module>
    print (struct.unpack('d', barray[:HALF_BYTES])[0])
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 8
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: What type is your barray? is it a bytearray() or a string? Also what are you trying to achieve, do you want to treat those 12 bytes as an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
int.from_bytes(barray[:HALF_BYTES], byteorder='big', signed=False)
```

to convert those 12 bytes to an integer, if thats what you are trying to do, assuming your barray is a bytearray() and you are using python 3.2 +

Comment: But I lose bytes right ? There is no 96 bits integer in phyton, That why I was trying to convert to floating point instead of integer.

Comment: Python can handle this, and converts it to a long internally, I believe. Edit: Just tested it, no precision is lost

Comment: That's great. I will use this.